# creating typescript classes to work with existing Javascript and Backbone objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript

I started working on a project where Backbone and Javascript are being used.  I'm unsure how to start integrating Typescript.  For example, we have a namespace of our company that precedes our views, models, objects, etc.  So creating a backbone object would look like this without typescript:

```
Company.Views.MyNewView = (function () { return Backbone.View.extend({ } })();
```

So now, using Typescript, I thought I could do something like

```
class Company.Views.MyNewView {

}
```

However, Typescript doesn't like the period in the name.  So my first question was how do I use Typescript with an existing namespace in my project?  Those namespaces are simply defined as

```
var Company = Company || {};
Company.Views = Company.Views || {};
```

My second question is more general.  Looking ahead, can Typescript easily integrate with an existing project where everything is defined with standard javascript?  I'm not sure really how to access any of my non-Typescript class objects.  Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Attempt to integrate with existing Javascript objects

```
declare module Company.Views {
    export class MyNewRouter extends Company.BaseRouter {
      // It does not recognize Company.BaseRouter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript has the concept of modules. A module is effectively equivalent to Company || {}.

So you can do the following :

```
module Company{
    export module Views{
        export function MyNewView(){
            return <any>Backbone.View.extend({ });
        }
    }
}
```

Which compiles into :

```
var Company;
(function (Company) {
    (function (Views) {
        function MyNewView() {
            return Backbone.View.extend({
            });
        }
        Views.MyNewView = MyNewView;
    })(Company.Views || (Company.Views = {}));
    var Views = Company.Views;
})(Company || (Company = {}));
```

**A simpler example**

The following typescript:

```
module Company{
    // You need to do at least one export 
    // for compiler to generate any code
    export var foo = 123;
}
```

generates:

```
var Company;
(function (Company) {
    Company.foo = 123;
})(Company || (Company = {}));
```

***For integrating existing JS***

You need to create declarations for typescript to know about your Js. Js doesn't care if you declare a variable in one file and use it in another. TypeScript does since it needs to do compile time checking.

The simplest declaration is :

```
declare var SomeJSStuff:any;
```

And you can [build up from there](http://basarat.github.io/TypeScriptDeepDive/#/declarations).

Comment: so it sounds like at least for the old namespaces, I at a minimum need to export them as modules?

Comment: No. If you want to use existing namespaces in typescript you use declarations. For new namespaces use modules

Comment: But if I have an already existing JS object that is called Company.BaseRouter, I can't extend that type can I?  I added the snippet I tried at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: added a second answer to address that

Comment: Ah I see.  So it sounds like without changing the current javascript namespaces since that would affect a lot of code right now, I'd have to declare a new module that my typescript can see that duplicates what already exists.  Is that going to cause problems later if I don't convert everything right away?

Comment: Nope. The amount of type safety you get would be proportional to the amount of type definitions (declarations) you give to typescript.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part the following is how you would do it:

```
// Declare your JS stuff
declare module Company {
    export class BaseRouter {
        // Additionally declare any memebers of BaseRouter
        // e.g:
        someProp:number; 
    }
}

// Now use your JS Stuff in typescript 
module Company.Views {
    export class MyNewRouter extends Company.BaseRouter {
      // It recognizes Company.BaseRouter
    }
}
```